# Mask RCNN, AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer

Tags: python, keras, mask-rcnn

I tried to run matterport/MaskRCNN.
Even though I've tried to change

`import keras.engine as KE` to `import keras.engine.topology as KE`

topology didn't work because topology module could not be resolved.

I've also tried

```
pip uninstall keras -y
pip uninstall keras-nightly -y
pip uninstall keras-Preprocessing -y
pip uninstall keras-vis -y
pip uninstall tensorflow -y
pip uninstall h5py -y
```

and install new by

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
pip install keras==2.0.8
pip install h5py==2.10.0
```

it didn't work because tensorflow's version error.

I've researched through github discussion and stackflow.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 16
     14 sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
     15 from mrcnn import utils
---> 16 import mrcnn.model as modellib
     17 from mrcnn import visualize
     18 # Import COCO config

File c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.10.egg\mrcnn\model.py:255
    251     clipped.set_shape((clipped.shape[0], 4))
    252     return clipped
--> 255 class ProposalLayer(KE.Layer):
    256     """Receives anchor scores and selects a subset to pass as proposals
    257     to the second stage. Filtering is done based on anchor scores and
    258     non-max suppression to remove overlaps. It also applies bounding
   (...)
    267         Proposals in normalized coordinates [batch, rois, (y1, x1, y2, x2)]
    268     """
    270     def __init__(self, proposal_count, nms_threshold, config=None, **kwargs):

AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change
"keras.engine as KE"
to
"keras.layers as KE"

Comment: This is a good answer. A friendly suggestion would be to highlight code snippets in "`" characters for a single line or "```" for code blocks. It makes them stand out a little better for reading.